# StoredProcedure not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am creating a procedure on new database. There is no any trigger on any table and no any procedure already exists. I am getting this error -

```
ERROR 1303 (2F003): Can't create a PROCEDURE from within another stored routine
```

What does this mean ? 
How to solve it ?

Comment: are you trying to create a database object from stored procedure ? I mean another stored procedure/function inside the stored procedure ?

Comment: We can't tell what it means unless you post your code. It might mean what it says, that you can't create a procedure within another stored routine - an error that you would get if you tried to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure must be trying to create a trigger or other stored procedure.

You can not create a trigger inside stored procedure.